# Python bootstrap threading error on remote host only

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have been running a script that contains three threads;

The main thread handles IRC messages, the second is a thread that containing a socket server that sends strings from IRC to a flash display when it connects as a client and the third is a socket server that sends the policy file which is a flash requirement when the client connects.

The python file runs fine my on "localhost", but when I host it on my linode it recieves the the first string only and sends the string response that is displayed on flash before crashing with the following error message.

The following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.3/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 616, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/opt/python3.3/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 682, in _bootstrap_inner
    self._stop()
TypeError: 'Event' object is not callable
```

Here is my socket server code:

```
class FlashSOCKET (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
        self._stop = threading.Event()
        self.stopWaitLoop = False
        self.conn = None
        self.addr = None
        self.HOST = None
        self.PORT = 7001
        self.s = None

    def run(self):
        global running, toSend, message
        print ("Starting " + self.name)
        while running:
            self.startListening()
            while running:
                if (messageDeque):
                    try:
                        print(self.conn.recv(1024))
                        self.conn.send(messageDeque.popleft().encode('utf8'))
                        print (messageDeque)
                        break
                    except:
                        pass # Nothing to do keep listening

            if (self.conn != None):
                self.close_connection()
        if (self.conn != None):
            self.close_connection()

        print ("Exiting " + self.name)

    def startListening(self):
        global running, message, toSend
        print ("starting to listen")
        for res in socket.getaddrinfo(self.HOST, self.PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC,
                                      socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
            af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
            try:
                self.s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
                self.s.settimeout(0.5)
            except socket.error as msg:
                self.s = None
                continue
            try:
                self.s.bind(sa)
                self.s.listen(1)

            except socket.error as msg:
                print ("socket error")
                self.s.close()
                self.s = None
                continue
            break
        if self.s is None:
            print ('could not open socket')
            sys.exit(1)
        while(running):
            try:
                self.conn, self.addr = self.s.accept()
                time.sleep(1)
                break
            except:
                continue
        print ('Connected by', self.addr)

    def close_connection(self):
        self.conn.close()
        print ("connection closed")
```

Running is a global bool flag variable that let me stop the program when I need to.
The messageDeque is a deque buffer that gets filled with strings in the main thread when people talk in IRC.

I think, toSend and message are bits of redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to avoid global variables. In normal programming they're sketchy, but in multithreaded programming they're more misleading than useful.
2. `Event` object: do `if self._stop.is_set()` vs checking a global